# Por que meu objeto só retorna undefined no alert enquanto retorna o valor normalmente no console?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Eu comecei a estudar javascript recentemente, e num dos meus primeiros códigos utilizando classe e objeto, meu navegador só retorna undefined no alerta (para tripulantes da nave, as outras propriedades do objeto parecem retornar normalmente). O que me deixa ainda mais confusa é que utilizando console.log, ele retorna os valores normais.

```
class Spaceship{
    constructor(name, crew){
        this.name = name
        this.crew = crew
        this.isHitched = false
        this.entranceDoorsOpen = false
    }

    hitchSpaceship(){
        this.isHitched = true
        this.entranceDoorsOpen = true
    }
}

let chosenOption 
let hitchedSpaceshipsList = []

while(chosenOption != 3){
    chosenOption = prompt(("O que deseja fazer?\n" +
                            "1- Engatar nave\n" +
                            "2- Imprimir naves cadasatradas\n" +
                            "3- Sair do programa"))
    switch(chosenOption){
        case "1":
            let spaceshipToAdd  = createSpaceship()
            spaceshipToAdd.hitchSpaceship()
            hitchedSpaceshipsList.push(spaceshipToAdd)
            break;
        case "2":
            printSpaceshipList(hitchedSpaceshipsList)
            break;
        case "3":
            alert("Saindo do programa!")
            break;
        default:
            alert("Opção inválida")
    }
} 

function printSpaceshipList(spaceship){
    let spaceshipList = ""
    spaceship.forEach((spaceship, index) => {
        spaceshipList += (index + 1) + 
                    spaceship.name + "\n" +
                    spaceship.crewQuantity + "\n" +
                    spaceship.isHitched + "\n" +
                    spaceship.entranceDoorsOpen
    });
    alert(spaceshipList)
}

function createSpaceship(){
    let spaceshipName = prompt("Qual o nome da nave?")
    let crewQuantity = Number(prompt("Qual o tamanho da tripulação?"))
    let spaceship = new Spaceship(spaceshipName, crewQuantity)
    return spaceship
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há dois possíveis problemas no código apresentado. O primeiro é que o prompt() retorna uma string, e você está comparando com o número 3 na linha 14. Para corrigir isso, basta adicionar o operador de igualdade estrita (===) na comparação. Ficaria assim:

```
while(chosenOption !== 3){
```

O segundo problema é que você está tentando acessar a propriedade `crewQuantity` do objeto `spaceship`, mas a propriedade correta é `crew`. Portanto, na linha 22, você deve alterar `spaceship.crewQuantity` para `spaceship.crew`.

```
spaceshipList += (index + 1) + 
                spaceship.name + "\n" +
                spaceship.crew + "\n" +
                spaceship.isHitched + "\n" +
                spaceship.entranceDoorsOpen
```

Com essas alterações, o código deve funcionar corretamente e exibir os valores esperados no alerta.